# Difference between assigning an Action<T> method and subscribing to Action<T> event

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, delegates

Lets say I have the below code. What is the difference between assigning the actions directly and subscribing to an event?

```
//Action directly assigned
public class ClassA
{
  public Action<string> OnAdd;

  private void SomethingHappened()
  {
     OnAdd("It Happened");
  }
}

public class ClassB
{

  public ClassB()
  {
    var myClass = new ClassA();
    myClass.OnAdd =  Add;
  }

  private void Add(string Input)
  {
    //do something
  }  
}

//Event handlers
public class ClassA
{
  public event Action<string> OnAdd;

  private void SomethingHappened()
  {
    if (OnAdd != null)
     OnAdd("It Happened"); //Should it be OnAdd.Invoke("It Happened") ???????
  }
}

public class ClassB
{

  public ClassB()
  {
    var myClass = new ClassA();
    myClass.OnAdd += Add;
  }

  private void Add(string Input)
  {
    //do something
  }  
}
```

Comment: Normally you will create an event with EventArgs<yourCustomEventArgs> instead of using an Action.

Comment: @SoMoS Even if its a just a string or int getting passed?

Comment: @jon this line `myClass.Add = myClass.OnAdd;` is not valid ... what is the `.Add` referes to ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thanks, well spotted. Have amended the code

Comment: @jon http://i.stack.imgur.com/LeUSA.jpg please look at the recommended pattern

Comment: @Jon, yes, even if its just a string. Even more, when you don't pass anything the pattern says that you should adhere to the object sender, EventArgs e signature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(As an aside, it's hard to explain things when you've used the same type names twice.)

When you use a public field, clients can not only subscribe to events - they can also *completely remove* other event handlers by assigning instead of adding:

```
myClass.OnAdd = Add;
```

They can also *invoke* the handler directly:

```
myClass.OnAdd("foo");
```

Both of these violate the normal pub/sub pattern, where the various subscribers are isolated from one another. Subscribers don't get to overwrite each other's subscriptions (only add or remove their own) and they don't get to raise the event themselves.

For more on events and delegates, see [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

Comment: as reading from your book - the event is alike property (getter setter) for the delegate chain , its like another protection level which doesnt lets users to do '='.( p.s. the torrent that youve sent me yesterday is 50GB !!:) ) but its worth it...:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, pretty much. Instead of get/set, it's add/remove.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the answer, using the same names illustrates the point of the question - what is the difference between two things that appear very similar

Comment: @jon but why when he writes `public Action<string> OnAdd;` you told him not to write public fields ? . if he add the `event` word - it will still be public field.... so what did you mean in `When you use a public field, clients can not only` ...he could only add the `event` keyword...no?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think this was aimed at @JonSkeet?? Valid question though. Whatever is written it will be public

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, with the `event` keyword it won't be a public *field*, it'll be a public *event* with a private underlying field.

Comment: @Jon: But when I'm trying to describe the differences between things, being able to refer to different names would help, e.g. `ClassWithField` vs `ClassWithEvent`.

Comment: @Jon: "Whatever is written it will be public" - there will be *a* public member, yes. But whether that's a public *field* or a public *event* makes an enormous difference to what external code can do.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign more than one delegates to one event (thus the `+=` operator).

Comment: You can create compound events if you just have a delegate field too... the point is that with events you *have* to just add a handler, instead of overwriting the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

An Event acts like a wrapper around a Delegate to offer protection from reassigning/removing as John has pointed out. I found [this](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html) quite a good read.